# Is it possible to use django with asgi and mantain some views on synced mode?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Now I have an application running under wsgi protocol, and now we are thinking about making a transition to the asgi protocol. The doubt we have to solve to make this decision is if it's possible to run django under asgi and keep some views on synced mode. Could anyone help me?

Comment: Yes, there will be a slight performance penalty though https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/async/#performance

Comment: Thanks! This fits well!